# Inconsistent datatypes expected NUMBER got DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, truncate

I am trying to run this query in Oracle as I need to extract data having Date falling in the previous month with respect to `sysdate`. This is what I wrote:

```sql
SELECT ID, BALANCE, DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE TRUNC(DATE, 'mm') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS((SYSDATE),-1),'mm');
```

The query does not work and returns the following message:

```
inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE.
```

Can anybody help me in solving this?

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5479832329c49d4e3506b3bbff5cab5c). Please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for the `my_table` table; and the DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Looks like you 'date' column is actually a string, which is not a good idea. (You can see the same error on [this modified db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8632f76d0acc6bd1942d9d9284e102ca).) Either change the column data type to an actual date, or if you really can't for some reason, you need to covert that string to a date before you truncate it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Be explicit about the data type of `date`.

Comment: "my Date field is NVARCHAR(2)" - so what are you holding in those two characters; a month number? Do you also have another column holding a year number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you've done something that is not best practice and your `DATE` column has the `NUMBER` data type (or `VARCHAR2`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( id NUMBER, balance NUMBER, "DATE" NUMBER );

INSERT INTO my_table ( id, balance, "DATE" ) VALUES ( 1, 100, 20210207012345 );
```

Then your query:

```sql
SELECT ID, BALANCE, "DATE"
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE TRUNC("DATE", 'mm') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS((SYSDATE),-1),'mm');
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
> ```

Not surprising as the `"DATE"` column is a `NUMBER` and not a `DATE` (or if you used `VARCHAR2` then `TRUNC` will implicitly cast the string to a `NUMBER` so it can truncate it as if it were a decimal value). The error message tells you what to do ... redefine the `"DATE"` column so that the data type matches the data being stored in the column, i.e. as a `DATE` data type.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( id NUMBER, balance NUMBER, "DATE" DATE );

INSERT INTO my_table (
  id, balance, "DATE"
) VALUES (
  1, 100, DATE '2021-02-07' + INTERVAL '01:23:45' HOUR TO SECOND
);
```

Then your query:

```sql
SELECT ID, BALANCE, "DATE"
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE TRUNC("DATE", 'mm') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS((SYSDATE),-1),'mm');
```

Works, and outputs:

> ```
> ID | BALANCE | DATE               
> -: | ------: | :------------------
>  1 |     100 | 2021-02-07 01:23:45
> ```

You could also use `TRUNC( TO_DATE( "DATE", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ), 'MM' )` in your query (with whichever format model is appropriate) but don't as this is a quick fix that does not address the underlying issue that you are using an inappropriate data type.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5bed902ce34c159637af9184f8dd4e04)*

Comment: Yes I can confirm my Date field is NVARCHAR(2) and I do not have permissions to modify it or to create temporary tables.

Comment: @SalvatoreVitale Then go and ask someone who has the permissions to modify it to change it to a sensible data type that accurately represents the data it is holding. Or else, use `TO_DATE` (as I mentioned in the last paragraph). But the proper solution should be to fix your data model.